# Lie subalgebras of $M_2(K)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am currently failing to understand a statement in a proof that is (maybe) considered too trivial to explain.

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero, and $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie-subalgebra of $M_2(K)$ satisfying the following properties:

1) $K^2$ is an irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$-module

2) The centralizer of $\mathfrak{g}$ in $M_2(K)$ is $K$, i.e. the only matrices commuting with all matrices in $\mathfrak{g}$ are of the form $\lambda E_2$, $E_2$ being the identity matrix.

Then, $\mathfrak{g}$ is either $M_2(K)$ or $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

I have no idea how to prove this, or how to find literature that covers this and would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $(2)$, the center of $\mathfrak{g}$ is at most $1$-dimensional. Since irreducible modules of solvable Lie algebras are $1$-dimensional by Lie's Theorem, $(1)$ says that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a non-solvable Lie algebra of dimension $n\le 4$. Together this leaves only $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_2(K)$.

Comment: This is only the notation. The associative matrix algebra $M_2(K)$ with its natural Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is denoted by $\mathfrak{gl}_2(K)$.

Comment: Your claim using Lie's theorem is false when $K$ is not algebraically closed ($K^2$ can be irreducible over 1-dimensional subalgebras if $K$ has quadratic field extensions). However, if $g$ is solvable, having an irreducible faithful module it has to be abelian, which is clearly not compatible with (1)+(2).

Comment: What is the argument for the fact, that a solvable lie algebra that has an irreducible faithful module has to be abelian?

Comment: Faithful means injective, and an injective map into a $1$-dimensional vector space limits the possibilities (see the answer above).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to reduce to the case that the module is a $1$-dimensional vector space

Comment: This is just Lie's Theorem, for $K$ algebraically closed. Then every nonzero irreducible module of a solvable Lie algebra has dimension $1$. A Lie algebra module is a representation into $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ for a vector space $V$. So $\dim(V)=1$ here.